# SDL mouse range on resize

Tags: linux, sdl

I am developing a SDL OpenGL application on Ubuntu and have noticed a problem with the mouse range when a new window size is set. The initiale size of my application is 600x400 and the mouse range (x,y) reflects this. However, when a user changes the screen to any other size (using given predefined sizes), the mouse range still only reflects a 600x400 screen size and causes issues with mouse location functionality.

To set the new resolution, I call:
`SDL_SetVideoMode(Width, Height, 32, SDL_OPENGL);` which to my understanding should handle the mouse range resizing but doesn't seem to do so in Linux. Can anyone give me a solution to this problem?

Note: Possible hack seem to be to exit SDL and re-initialize using `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found the problem was that I was calling `SDL_GetMouseState(0,0)` later after the size change was made which apparently was interfering with the recalculation of the mouse range. However, I've gone through the SDL source but I can't really determine how this would effect it so. There seems to be some mouse state switching that may be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime i resize the window, I execute the following to refresh my viewport:

```
m_ParentWindow = SDL_SetVideoMode( m_width, m_height, m_depth, m_SDL_Vid_Flags );

glViewport(0,0,m_width,m_height);

Clear();
```

Where Clear calls:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: I also call `glViewport(0,0,m_width,m_height);` already and I call `glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);`. I will try loading the identity matrix and calling glClear. I wasn't sure if this was an openGL problem so I didn't include any of that information.

Comment: Hmm did you refresh your perspective? gluPerspective? I also use that but didn't think it was necessary to fix the mouse coordinates, unless you are zooming.

Comment: Not doing any zooming. Basically it's a launcher that allows the user to select a resolution / size and then launches the main app at that size. I feel like it shouldn't be an openGL problem but I will attempt these proposals.